# How to set CORS header?

Tags: plugins, admin, options, media-settings

I have been accessing media images in a Ruby on Rails application via ajax from wordpress 4.2.4.

I am getting following error while accessing the image via ajax.

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myblog/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/test.jpeg. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://stage.mysite.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

I tried [WP-CORS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-cors) plugin and set `*` as allowed domains but it doesn't work. I verified that the response doesn't have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

I am not wordpress/php guy so would appreciate for simplest possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by adding `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` in `apache2.conf`:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Require all granted
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</Directory>
```

Comment: It is possible but only a very small amount of people will be able to do that. You should probably do it in .htaccess or even better at the PHP level.